# ¿Como puedo hacer para que este algoritmo me muestre la fila y columna donde esta el dato que busco?

Tags: pseint

Este Algoritmo esta hecho en pseudocodigo en el programa SLE (O bien se puede hace en PSeInt) y estoy utilizando subrutinas para hacer este problema. Cuando introduzco un dato no me da la posicion exacta en donde esta el dato que deseo saber, pienso que mi problema puede estar en la subrutina **busqueda_dato**. Ya que, le estoy devolviendo el dato donde se encuentra pero al llegar a la condicion para saber en que posicion esta no me muestra con seguridad la posicion del dato.

Por favor, agradeceria que me hicieran ver mi error y me enseñaran. Muchas gracias, :)

```
  const
        N = 3
    var 
        i, j, k, buscador : numerico
        m : matriz[N, N] numerico
    inicio
        cls()

    i = 1 

    mientras (i <= N)
    {
     j = 1
     mientras (j <= N)
     {
      m[i, j] = random(19)
      j = j + 1
     }
     i = i + 1 
    }

    imprimir ("\n Vector: ")
    imprimir ("\n ")
    imprimir (" ")
    imprimir_vector(m)

    imprimir ("\n ")

    imprimir ("\n Introduzca un valor a buscar: ")
    imprimir ("\n ")
    leer(buscador)

    k = busqueda_dato(m, buscador)

    si (k == 0)
    {
     imprimir ("\n Elemento no encontrado en la matriz ")
    sino 
     imprimir ("\n Elemento encontrado en la fila ", i, " columna ", j)
    }

    imprimir ("\n")

    imprimir ("\n Matriz: ")
    imprimir ("\n ")
    imprimir (" ")
    imprimir_vector(m)
fin 

subrutina busqueda_dato(ref m : matriz [N, N] numerico; buscador : numerico) retorna numerico 
var 
    i, j, k, elemento : numerico
    encontrar : logico
inicio 
    encontrar = FALSE
    elemento = 0
    i = 1
    mientras (i <= N and not(encontrar))
    {
     j = 1
     mientras (j <= N and not(encontrar))
     {
        k = 1
        mientras (k <= N and not(encontrar))
        {
         si (m[i, j] == buscador)
            {
                encontrar = TRUE
                elemento = m[i, j]
            }
            k = k + 1
        }
        j = j + 1
     }
     i = i + 1
    }
    retorna(elemento)
fin 

subrutina imprimir_vector(m : matriz[N, N] numerico)
var 
    i, j : numerico 
inicio 
    i = 1
    j = 1
    desde i = 1 hasta N
    {
     desde j = 1 hasta N 
     {
        imprimir (m[i, j], " ")
     }
     imprimir ("\n ")
    }
fin
```

Comment: veo 2 problemas.. no se porque recorres una matriz de dos dimensiones, usando 3 iteradores.. para que usas k?? con i y j alcanzaba.. y otra cosa.. i y j, dentro de busquedadato, no son el mismo i y j de tu funcion principal... vos encontras el numero, pero devolves el numero encontrado, no j e i.....

Comment: Como puedo devolver esa ubicacion utilizando mi 'j' e 'i'? Para que asi me muestra donde esta ese numero.

Comment: no se si se puede en pseint.. desconozco ese lenguaje

Comment: Se puede en PSeInt. Yo estoy utilizando un IDE que es SLE con un lenguaje que se llama SL. SL SL es un lenguaje diseñado para apoyar la formación profesional de estudiantes de Informática. Como es Pseudocodigo tambien se puede hacer en PSeInt

Comment: Genial.. si vos sabes que se puede, entonces porque me preguntaste si se podia????

Comment: En realidad no pregunte si se podia hacer en PSeInt. Mi pregunta fue la siguiente:  Como puedo devolver esa ubicacion utilizando mi 'j' e 'i'?. Pero de todos modos muchisimas gracias. Ya resolvi mi problema